# Can't connect iPad to macOS Mojave

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode

I used to be able to recognize iPad when working with Xcode and iTunes in previous versions of macOS.

Now I can no longer connect it. System Information does contain the device in USB list and the Image Capture application shows an "iPad" in the list, but nothing else can be done to it. Even iTunes can't see it.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What model of iPad?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that could be wrong is not stepping through the guide to triage this:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204095

The once iTunes can see the device, repeat for the next app if needed.

Comment: I have gone through it. In another mac it works with the same cable.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Does the System profiler see the iPad connected on both computers the same? @ me if you want me to edit the answer with a screen shot or more words how to check the above